# push wagon site to locomotivecms engine ssl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms, wagon

I have a wagon site fully working that I can see when I start the server

I have a working LocomotiveCMS engine on my machine

Now I would like to deploy the wagon site to the engine as described in the guide on the locomotivecms website

I have edited the deploy.yml file to have details of the locomotive engine site administrator account. (locomotive url on my localhost; email; password)

I try to push the whole site using **bundle exec wagon push staging** and I receive this complaint : 'unable to get an API token: localhost:8080/locomotive/locomotive/api/tokens.json does not respond. Perhaps, the ssl option is missing in your config/deploy.yml file'

I like the locomotive engine but as now I cannot get to it to work with the wagon site that I have made.

Github link https://github.com/LucaDev13/wagon_zurb

Can someone shed some light on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess based on the response you are getting. It is showing the directory structure as "/locomotive/locomotive."

So my guess would be that you have defined the host as `http://localhost:8080/locomotive` so, unless that is in fact the correct directory structure, I would suggest changing the host to `http://localhost:8080` (removing the /locomotive) and then try again.

Comment: Hi, This answer is absolutely correct. In fact when using http://localhost:8080 the deployment has been executed immediately.